# SIngle-file generator changes in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to find information on single-file generator changes (especially how to register) in Visual Studio 2017. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem too. In VS 2015 the registry key was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Gene‌​rators. There is no equivalent for VS 2017?!?

Answer (score 12):

I think the registration system is pretty much the same. You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/registering-single-file-generators)

In Visual Studio 2017, the registry settings are stored in a private registry files.

This enables multiple installations of Visual Studio side by side, on the same machine.

However, these entries are no longer available in the global registry file.

Here is how to open such a file in regedit:

- Close Visual Studio
- Start Regedit.exe
- Select the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` node
- From the main menu, select `File` -> `Load Hive...` and select the private registry file. That file is stored in the Local App Data

  `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<config>\privateregistry.bin`

  where `<config>` coresponds to the configuration hive you would like to use
- It will prompt for a name - that represents the name that will be displayed under (e.g. `IsolatedHive`)
- Now you should be able to browse the registry under the hive you created
- Before launching Visual Studio, you need to unload it: From the main menu `File` -> `Unload Hive` before attempting to run VS (otherwise regedit keeps the file locked, and Visual Studio will fail to launch)

Comment: How are you supposed to do it in the installer?

Comment: Also, this location is per user, where our single-file generator is registered per machine.

Comment: This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/breaking-changes-2017) explains the extensibility breaking changes in Visual Studio 2017 and provides guidance on how to port existing extensions:

Comment: @alex-i Prior to VS2017, I was manually installing my Single-File Generator (which is housed in a C# class-library project) using a batch file with REG commands. Now that the registry is in a private hive (and the path to that hive is different per VS installation), I changed my installation method to a VSIX. If you like, I can share the details of how I did that.

Comment: @harley.333, if you have some sample code to share, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @harley.333, yes, do share. I had earlier given up on installing a single file generator as a VSIX because VSIXs do not provide a way to change registry settings or, AFAIK, run custom code when VS starts.